# Mongo update if unique index violated

Tags: mongodb, indexing, unique-constraint, insert-update, spring-data

I wonder if there is a way ( configuration / operation ), which allows to update (add new data from the inserted record like in save()) the existing document in the DB while trying to insert other document which violates the unique index..??

Thanks

I have SocialProfile document which represent domain user profile which related specific social network. 
I want to use the combination of the social network type + user unique in that network as unique. 
**{ type : "FB" , unique:"1111111111" }** 
At first i thought about combining these two strings into one and use the concatenation as the document ID and then the upsert will happens automatically while saving documents but it feel like the wrong approach correct in if I am wrong.
 
more make sense is to define these to properties as compound unique index.. 
and I want the ability to perform upsert of these documents according to that index..
I am working with Spring Data framework how do I support this kind of operation in general and In spring data specific.
Thanks for helping

Comment: Use an upsert? That's practically the canonical use case.

Comment: upsert know if to update according to the document Id or Unique index or both?

Comment: upsert in mongo is save method and it work according to the document id ... the purpose is to use other fields in the document as unique except from the document id

Comment: You can pass a query into update for upsert. I'm a little confused about your exact goal, can you provide some sample data before and after?

Answer (score 3):

As Chris said, upsert is probably the right way to do this. Do you have some example data? Here's quick example:

```
db.coll.update(
  /* query */ {keys:"from", unique:"index"}, 
  /* new document */ {keys:"from", unique:"index", new_value:"foo"}, 
  /* upsert */ true, 
  /* multi */ false);
```

It will query for a document with the keys specified in the query, and if it exists, it will update that document with the document provided. If that document doesn't exist, it will create a new document.